# AWS IoT Rule: Get control packet type

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, iot, aws-iot

I'd like to log MQTT messages to persistent storage and log their control packet type, e.g. `CONNECT, CONNACK, PUBLISH, SUBSCRIBE` etc. Specifically I would like to use IoT SQL to only apply a rule where the control packet type is something specific, e.g. `PUBLISH`. Is this possible, I didn't see a relevant function to retrieve this information in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sql-functions.html). Something like `SELECT *, [control packet type] as method FROM '#' WHERE method = 'PUBLISH'`, where the brackets would be replaced with the value I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the rules engine then you can infer the control packet type by the relevant topic. Rules that run against [reserved topics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/cloud-watch-logs.html#message-broker-logs) will allow you to trigger actions based on connect, disconnect, subscribe and unsubscribe control packets. A rule on all unreserved topics ('#') will correspond to a publish message.

There is also some metadata available in the [message broker logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/topics.html#reserved-topics).

Comment: Thanks wasn't sure that's how the rules engine worked vis a vis unreserved vs reserved topics.

Comment: Sorry on reserved topics, how will I know which of the 4 control packets invoked the rule?

Comment: It is implied by the specific reserved topic name. e.g. `$aws/events/presence/connected/+` will correlate to all connect packets. There are different reserved topics that correspond to disconnect, subscribe and unsubscribe packets.